# markDone on Task object

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I am trying to utilize the markDone action on the Task Object.  My guess is that this is a PUT, but I have tried a POST.  I have yet to try the GET with the parameter of PUT or POST, that I will try next.  However I would prefer not to go this route.  I am fairly new to Web API's and this is my first attempt at writing an API that talks to another API, so that could be playing into the issue.  I am utilizing the HttpClient object and have tried PostAsync and PutAsync.  Below is what I have currently.

```
    using (var apiManagementSystem = new HttpClient())
    {
        apiManagementSystem.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxxxxxx.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/");
        apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SessionID", "xxxxxxx");
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent("?ID=xxxxxxx&action=markDone&status=CPL");
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = apiManagementSystem.PutAsync("Task", httpContent).Result;
    }
```

Even if you don't know if the above code is right maybe you would know what the URL would be or the headers should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to help here but I am mostly working in Python and Javascript/Node. Regarding marking a task as done via an action, this would be a PUT call. Here is an example URL using the API key authentication method. For session key you would just switch to sessionID

```
https://xxx.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v6.0/task/582df5e700e6243a8656824931a495b7?apiKey=xxxxxxx&action=markDone
```

The UID after /task/ is the ID number of the task.

Comment: I just got done trying this and it isn't working for me.  I am getting a 400 and WorkFront is returning a message of No Assignment was Found.  However I can do a Get for my ID and it returns my object.

Comment: One thing that I noticed was your URL.  I have been trying domain/attask/api/task/xxxxx..... and you have domain/attask/api/v6.0.  I have seen others use this approach as well.  When my URL doesn't have the version I get a 400.  When I target the version I get a 403 (forbidden) with the same error.  This leads me to believe that my request for the URL without the version is really a permissions issue.  I'm assuming leaving off the version targets the most recent api.  Is this correct?

Comment: another thing that I should note is that I have the HttpContent object as null.  I know you aren't working with C#, but I figured I should put it here just in case it helped you or others.

Comment: Brandon, are you authenticating using an API key or session ID?

Comment: I am using a session ID.

Comment: Your answer was the correct answer.  There was a misunderstanding by me.  I thought that the API key gave you rights to perform any operation that you needed, turns out that is not the case.  In my case I was trying to mark a task as done that belonged to somebody else.  The api key was assigned to me and the assignee of the task was a coworker.  When I assigned me to the task and used the markDone action then this worked.

Comment: Do you know how to mark a task as done that does not belong to you?

Comment: @BrandonHunt You must have manage rights on the task (such as a PM role) or be a system administrator. If you're scripting this, it may make sense to have a dedicated sysadmin account that you use to execute privileged scripts under.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C# code to perform this operation

```
using (var apiManagementSystem = new HttpClient())
{
    apiManagementSystem.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxxxxxx.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/");
    apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

    HttpContent httpContent = null;
    responseMessage = apiManagementSystem.PutAsync("TASK/TASKIDxxx?action=markDone&apiKey=apikeyxxx", httpContent).Result;

}
```